# React Three.js make objects in scene larger, similar to canvas size

Tags: javascript, reactjs, animation, three.js

[image]

The `canvas` in the image above is large but the `scene` small. How can I make the `scene` or 3D objects in the `scene` larger and perhaps match the height and width of the `canvas`?

Code:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import React3 from 'react-three-renderer';
import * as THREE from 'three';

class Graph3D extends Component {
    constructor(props, context) {
        super(props, context);

        this.cameraPosition = new THREE.Vector3(0, 0, 5);

        this.state = {
            origin: new THREE.Vector3(0, 0, 0),

            vector1: new THREE.Vector3(0, 0.5, 0.5),
            vector2: new THREE.Vector3(0.2, 0.3, 0.1),
            vector3: new THREE.Vector3(0.2, 0.4, 0.1),
            vector4: new THREE.Vector3(0.6, 0.8, 0),
            vector5: new THREE.Vector3(0.9, 0.9, 0.9),
            vector6: new THREE.Vector3(0.2, 0.8, 0.9),
        };
    }

    render() {
        const width = window.innerWidth; // canvas width
        const height = window.innerHeight; // canvas height

        return (<React3
          mainCamera="camera" // this points to the perspectiveCamera which has the name set to "camera" below
          width={width}
          height={height}
          clearColor={'#ffffff'}
        >
            <scene>
                <perspectiveCamera
                  name="camera"
                  fov={75}
                  aspect={width / height}
                  near={0.1}
                  far={1000}

                  position={this.cameraPosition}
                />

                 <arrowHelper
                   origin={this.state.origin}
                   dir={this.state.vector1}
                 />

                <arrowHelper
                  origin={this.state.origin}
                  dir={this.state.vector2}
                />

                 <arrowHelper
                   origin={this.state.origin}
                   dir={this.state.vector3}
                 />

                <arrowHelper
                  origin={this.state.origin}
                  dir={this.state.vector4}
                />
                <arrowHelper
                  origin={this.state.origin}
                  dir={this.state.vector5}
                />
                <arrowHelper
                  origin={this.state.origin}
                  dir={this.state.vector6}
                />

            </scene>
        </React3>);
    }
}
```

With this code above the `canvas` gets the size of the `screen` but for some reason all my `arrowHelpers` and my `scene` are small in comparison.

How do I make them larger?

I tried assigning larger values to my `Vectors` but that didn't help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try moving the camera closer to the scene:

```
 this.cameraPosition = new THREE.Vector3(0, 0, 2);
```

You can also make the arrows longer. The reason why it did not work to assign larger values is that they are only *direction* vectors. There is a third optional argument to `ArrowHelper` that is the length of the arrow:

```
<arrowHelper
    origin={this.state.origin}
    dir={this.state.vector3}
    length={2}
/>
```

Comment: Thanks but it comes off extremely pixelated. How do I prevent that? Trying to go through the docs but so much information -- I;m trying to play with the `fov` `far` and `near` props but not helping much